# Adjust elapsed time for 5 hours?

Tags: bash

I have the following script that basically looks for a certain process name and tracks if it's elapsed for more than X time, to kill it.

```
#!/bin/bash

PROC_NAME=my_proc_name

# Get all PIDs for process name
procs=(`ps aux | grep  $PROC_NAME | awk '{print $2}'`)

# for each PID in PIDs array
for pid in $procs; do
    # get elapsed time in form mm:ss and remove ":" character
    # to make it easier to parse time 
    time=(`ps -o etime $pid | sed -e 's/[:-]/ /g'`)
    # get minutes from time
    min=${time[1]}
    # if proces runs 5 hours then kill it
    if [ "$min" -gt "300" ]; then
        kill -9 $pid
    fi
done;
```

This version of the script kills the process if the elapsed time exceeds 5 mins. But what if i want to account for an elapsed time of 5 hours instead?

I thought it'd be as simple as adjusting 5 mins to 300 mins (60 mins x 5 = 300mins = 5 hours) but I realized that the format is hours:min:secs .. so will need to make sure Sed gets the hours, right? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: if the process has been running for more than 5 hours what does `typeset -p time` show as the contents of the `time[]` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash regular expression to get different components :

```
#!/bin/bash

PROC_NAME=my_proc_name

# Get all PIDs for process name
procs=(`ps aux | grep  $PROC_NAME | awk '{print $2}'`)

pattern='((.*)-)?((..):)?(..):(..)'

for pid in ${procs[@]}; do
    if [[ "$(ps -o etime= -p $pid)" =~ $pattern ]] && {
       [ -n "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ] || # if day component exists, then it's more than 5 hours
       { [ -n "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}" ] && ((10#${BASH_REMATCH[4]} >= 5)); } }; then
        echo kill -9 $pid
    fi
done
```

Remove `echo` (dry run) if you see the result is expected.

Explanation of pattern='((.*)-)?((..):)?(..):(..)' :

```
1) ((.*)-)? means optional day component
   if present like 9- then ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} = 9-, ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} = 9
   if absent, ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} is empty
2) ((..):)? means optional hour component
   if present like 05 then ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} = 05:,${BASH_REMATCH[4]} = 05
   if absent, ${BASH_REMATCH[4]} is empty
```

Comment: Oh interesting! I'm kinda new to bash, can you elaborate on the REMATCH component pattern? Also the echo command in this case is basically a dry-run/what if scenario right

Comment: sweet thanks for adding explanations. also i noticed `#${BASH_REMATCH[4]} >= 5)); } }; then` is commented, not sure if thats intentional

Comment: That's not comment. `#` goes with `10` in `10#` to specify base 10, otherwise bash would throw error on 08 (or 09).

Comment: ahhhh interesting! its like ASCII encoding

Answer (score 0):

Usually, on many systems, I transform the `ps` elapsed time in seconds with `awk`:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

...

declare -i E_TIME=$(ps \
    -p ${THE_PID} \
    -o etime=     \
| awk '
    {
        gsub(/^ +/, "")
        gsub(/ +$/, "")
    }
    /^[0-9]*-/ {
        days = $0
        gsub(/-.*$/, "", days)
        gsub(/^0+/,  "", days)
        if (days == "") days = "0"
        gsub(/^[0-9]+-/, "", $0)
    }
    /^[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/ {
        hours = $0
        gsub(/:.*$/, "", hours)
        gsub(/^0+/,  "", hours)
        if (hours == "") hours = "0"
        gsub(/^[0-9]+:/, "", $0)
    }
    /^[0-9]+:[0-9]+$/ {
        minutes = $0
        gsub(/:.*$/, "", minutes)
        gsub(/^0+/,  "", minutes)
        if (minutes == "") minutes = "0"
        gsub(/^[0-9]+:/, "", $0)
    }
    /^[0-9]+$/ {
        seconds = $0
        gsub(/:.*$/, "", seconds)
        gsub(/^0+/,  "", seconds)
        if (seconds == "") seconds = "0"
    }
    {
        print seconds + 60 * (minutes + 60 * (hours + 24 * days) )
    }
'
)

echo "E_TIME=${E_TIME}"
```

Comment: I see, so this transforms the time only to seconds, so all I would have to do is modify the loop: `if [ "${E_TIME}" -gt "18000" ]; then
        kill -9 $pid
    fi` in which 18000 is 5 hours equivalent, right?

Comment: @Cataster : Yes!